# How to show belongsTomany data in a datatable

Tags: sql, laravel, datatable

DataTables warning: table id=dataTableBuilder - Exception Message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'phyto_product' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `phyto_product` left join `phyto_product` on `phyto_product`.`id` = `phytos`.`phyto_id` left join `phyto_product` on `phyto_product`.`id` = `products`.`product_id` where `phyto_product`.`deleted_at` is null) count_row_table)

I have a `belongsTomany` relationship between phyto and product as follows. I'm looking for  a way to display in the `datatable` the following

`phyto_number, product_name, weight, charge`

My query (PhytoProduct is a pivot table)

```
 public function query(PhytoProduct $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery()->leftjoin('phyto_product','phyto_product.id', '=','phytos.phyto_id')
        ->leftjoin('phyto_product','phyto_product.id', '=', 'products.product_id')
        ->select('phyto_product.*', 'phytos.phyto_number','products.product_name');
    }
```

My datatable

```
 protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [

            [ 'data' => 'phyto_number', 'name' => 'phytos.phyto_number', 'title' => 'Phyto Number' ],
            [ 'data' => 'product_name', 'name' => 'products.product_name', 'title' => 'Product Name' ],
            [ 'data' => 'weight', 'name' => 'phyto_product.weight', 'title' => 'Weight' ],
            [ 'data' => 'charge', 'name' => 'phyto_product.charge', 'title' => 'charge' ],

        ];
    }
```

Phyto Model

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Eloquent as Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * Class Phyto
     * @package App\Models
     * @version December 27, 2019, 1:08 am UTC
     *
     * @property string phyto_number
     * @property integer destination_id
     * @property string indate
     */
    class Phyto extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        public $table = 'phytos';

        const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
        const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';


        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



        public $fillable = [
            'phyto_number',
            'destination_id',
           'indate'
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'id' => 'integer',
            'phyto_number' => 'string',
            'destination_id' => 'integer',
            'indate' => 'date:d/m/y',
        ];

        /**
         * Validation rules
         *
         * @var array
         */
        public static $rules = [
            'phyto_number' => 'required',
            'indate' => 'required'
        ];


        public function products()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(['weight','charge']);
        }
        public function destinations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Destination::class);
        }

    }

PhytoProduct Model

    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Eloquent as Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * Class PhytoProduct
     * @package App\Models
     * @version December 27, 2019, 2:20 am UTC
     *
     * @property integer phyto_id
     * @property integer product_id
     * @property number weight
     * @property number charge
     */
    class PhytoProduct extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        public $table = 'phyto_product';

        const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
        const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';


        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



        public $fillable = [
            'phyto_id',
            'product_id',
            'weight',
            'charge'
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'id' => 'integer',
            'phyto_id' => 'integer',
            'product_id' => 'integer',
            'weight' => 'float',
            'charge' => 'float'
        ];

        /**
         * Validation rules
         *
         * @var array
         */
        public static $rules = [
            'phyto_id' => 'required',
            'product_id' => 'required'
        ];


    }

Product Model

    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Eloquent as Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * Class Product
     * @package App\Models
     * @version December 27, 2019, 1:07 am UTC
     *
     * @property string product_name
     */
    class Product extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        public $table = 'products';

        const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
        const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';


        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



        public $fillable = [
            'product_name'
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $casts = [
            'id' => 'integer',
            'product_name' => 'string'
        ];

        /**
         * Validation rules
         *
         * @var array
         */
        public static $rules = [
            'product_name' => 'required'
        ];

        public function phytos()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(['weight','charge']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on this sql

```
SELECT phyto_product.weight,
phytos.phyto_number,
products.product_name 
FROM phyto_product 
LEFT JOIN phytos ON phytos.id = phyto_product.phyto_id 
Left join products ON products.id = phyto_product.product_id
```

and then translated into this

```
  public function query(PhytoProduct $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery()->leftjoin('phytos','phytos.id', '=', 'phyto_product.phyto_id')
        ->leftjoin('products','products.id', '=', 'phyto_product.product_id')
        ->select('phyto_product.*', 'phytos.*','products.*');
    }
```